# What are the Indeed work attitude assessments looking for anyway?

Tags: applications

I've been prompted to do Indeed skills assessments sometimes when applying for jobs. Some of them are straightforward assessments of knowledge. Others aren't as straightforward and ask questions along the lines of 'would you rather work well with others or not be dishonest'. These assessments (*supposedly*) measure soft skills like reliability or accountability

I haven't done well on some of this type and am looking to improve, but I'm not sure exactly how to do this. Does anyone have any insight?

The thing Indeed's assessments aren't a you-can't-fail type strengths weaknesses personality quiz. It's grading you from bad to good. Here's how they describe it:

> Indeed’s assessments are scored with ratings — from high to low — of
> “Expert,” “Highly Proficient,” “Proficient,” “Familiar” and
> “Completed.”

I'm trying to get expert or highly proficient and avoid familiar and completed

There's been quite a bit of confusion about how Indeed assessments work, so I'm going to break it down further. The test grading is a lot like grades in school. Expert is like an A, highly proficient is like a B and so on. An employer is like your parents looking at your report card. They see the results but they don't have any say in the process that led there, nor even knowledge of what exactly led to you getting that grade. The assessments are this black box that this score comes out of. The company selects an assessment from a list and gets a score. Indeed describes it as

> We developed Indeed Assessments to help you screen your applicants for
> skills that matter most to you — whether that’s hard skills, like
> sales or accounting, industry knowledge like medical billing or food
> safety, or soft skills like reliability and accountability

There's no upside to doing poorly on the soft skills assessments, as some people have suggested. No employer wants to hire someone who's unreliable, and if they don't care if their employees are reliable they won't select that assessment

If I got a poor score on something like food safety, I could learn more about the topic and improve my knowledge. But for the weird, vague soft skills assessments, it's not so straightforward. This is why I'm asking my question. I want to do better, but the path forward isn't clear

Comment: @Shane You should write a clearer question, and elaborate. Joe sounds right to me. To me, the non-straightforward question sounds like it comes from a personality quiz like Strengths Finder or DISC. Just be honest.

Comment: Keep in mind that in many cases, the 'right' answer will depend on the company and culture. In some companies, being a team player will be far more important than being 100% honest all the time, while in others (especially highly regulated industries) honesty will be far more important even if it means creating bad blood between coworkers.

Comment: @Joe- Sorry, I now realize I wasn't very clear about how the assessments are graded. I edited my question and hopefully it's more clear now what I was looking for help with

Comment: Could you link these non-straightforward quizzes you reference? That would help.

Comment: I don't think I can. From what I can find it looks like the ability to take a quiz without being invited by an employer has been removed. I'll see if I can find something comparable that's more accessible

Answer (score 3):

**If you want the job**

Answer in line with the company leadership principles/whatever information you can find about their values online. Taking a look at my company's careers page, [there is a values statement](https://www.altaml.com/careers/). If you answer in line with that, you should pass. Many companies are upfront about what they want to hear, so give them what they want to hear.

**If you trust their HR to properly analyze you for fit**

Answer honestly.

Comment: I really like this answer for if I get this kind of assessment on a company website. The problem with Indeed is it's the same tests for every company, they can't customize it and they only see your score. It's like a grade in school. Nobody outside the school knows how you got that grade, they just know how you did with no other context

Comment: @Joe This isn't actually how the Indeed assessments work. There's been a lot of confusion on that and I edited my question *again* to hopefully make it more clear. Hope the edits clear up the confusion